# worklight native to web ios

Tags: ios, ibm-mobilefirst

Working on worklight 6.0.I have created a ios native component inside a hybrid application.I am having three buttons in HomePage.html page.when clicking one of the button,I am navigating to the native page using **WL.NativePage.show** method. In Native page I am having Back and Proceed Button. When clicking Back button, it is getting navigated again to HomePage.html page using the [NativePage showWebView:returnedData] method, When clicking Proceed button also it is navigating to HomePage.html page.
How to load the another html page (Carousel) when Proceed button is clicked.
I tried using

```
    function backFromNativePage(data)
     {

        $("HomePage").load("html/Carousel.html", function()
           {
               alert("level2");
           }
    }
```

But no luck...
Can anyone help me to solve this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect that something else in your app is at fault. Can you produce a demo project exhibiting it?

I've modified [the Native Pages sample project](http://public.dhe.ibm.com/software/mobile-solutions/worklight/docs/v610/UsingNativePagesInHybridAppsProject.zip) so that upon returning from the native page it will load another HTML file instead of index.html.

Here is the modified project: [Web <-> Native Multi-page navigation](https://www.dropbox.com/s/thqxtffocc9zfcf/NativeWebMultiPageNavigation.zip)